# Empty title for downvote/removal entries of articles in Activity>Reputation view

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page, reputation-history, articles

Looking at the Activity>Reputation view of my own profile, I see nothing where the title of the post should be:

[image]

The posts in question were articles posted by a [plagiarist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422772/collective-article-written-by-one-person-and-posted-by-another) employed by Microsoft.

---

Actually, if I force a refresh, the title text seems to briefly flash before disappearing. It also doesn't happen in Chrome, or Edge, just in the slightly older version of Firefox I have on one machine (v89 -- is it really that broken and not supported by SO?).

Comment: IIRC, SE only officially support the last 2 major versions of the most common browsers, so FF 104+ (maybe 103+?). Does it happen in a modern version of Firefox?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine That might be it. Is backwards compatibility really that dreadful even regarding rendering of content? And is there some reference regarding what browsers  (and their versions) are officially supported that I missed?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a web developer, and having code that doesn't work even a decade later is a bit odd to me.

Comment: "[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/271271)"

Comment: While it would be possible to determine what exact change in Firefox between FF89 and current is causing the issue, you'll probably need to do that yourself, potentially by looking in the browser console for errors, as A) the vast majority of people will have upgraded away from FF89 more than a year ago, and B) the example you've provided is visible *only* to you. Information about your loss of reputation due to you downvoting and the return of that reputation when the post is deleted is only displayed to you (or *maybe* some SE staff), so nobody else is going to be able to check this one.

Comment: I've added a [meta-tag:status-declined] tag here, which is how reports of issues that are specific to older browsers are supposed to end up. If you experience this issue in a supported browser/browser version, please [edit] to indicate that and raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request the [meta-tag:status-declined] tag be removed.